# Regexp valid email check

Tags: php, regex, validation, email, email-validation

I try to check if an email is valid with the following regexp code.

```
/[0-9A-Za-z-_.]{1,64}[\@][0-9a-zA-Z\-]{1,63}[\.][a-zA-Z\-]{2,24}/
```

But in Tests I see that invalid emails like `test---@gmail.com` or `test-.-@gmail.com` or `test-.@gmail.com` or `test.@gmail.com` or `test__@gmail.com` or `__--.test@gmail.com` are marked as valid.

I think in no valid email is . , _ , - on beginning or ending and not behind each other like -- or __ or -. or .- ...

What I could do to make it better?

Comment: "What I could do to make it better?" --- you could not validate emails with a regexp.

Comment: Most of your examples **are** valid emails.

Comment: @AlexHowansky how you come to this opinion? Have you ever tried to register those emails for example by outlook.com or gmail.com ?

Comment: @zerkms what is this for an answer? Any other good idea from you ;-)

Comment: _"how you come to this opinion?"_ See [RFC822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc822.txt) section 6.1.

Comment: @AlexHowansky yes can be but by every big normal provider it isn't possible to use . , _ , - in beginning or ending or behind each other. Have tried different freemail provider and registration such emails is impossible there.

Comment: @Mann87 sure - just check if the string contains `@` character. If it is - it looks like an email. The rest depends on what you need the email for (which you did not describe).

Comment: @zerkms for example emails like sarah_-@gmail.com don't work and I need the regex to prevent those emails. I need the email check for an customer database tool, that was created by an programmer years before. I only can change there regex.

Comment: @Mann87 I believe it's a valid email address. If you need to be sure the email is accepted by the remote mail server and exists - send an email there.

Comment: "I only can change there regex" --- some problems cannot be solved with just regular expressions. This one is one of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one:

```
^(|(([A-Za-z0-9]+_+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\-+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\.+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\++))*[A-Za-z0-9]+@((\w+\-+)|(\w+\.))*\w{1,63}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})$
```

another way:

```
^(|(([A-Za-z0-9]+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\++))*[A-Za-z0-9]+@((\w+\-+)|(\w+\.))*\w{1,63}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})$
```

no match:

```
test-.@gmail.com
test.@gmail.com
test__@gmail.com
__--.test@gmail.com
john__doe@gmail.com
john..doe@xuse.de
john--doe@xuse.de
test_test@gmail.com
```

match:

```
12test21@gmail.com
1.test@gmail.com
test.test@gmail.com
```

Comment: Thanks I have tried this it work realy better than this one I used before. Thank you very much.

Comment: john__doe@gmail.com, john..doe@xuse.de also john--doe@xuse.de still work but is also such an email that is not valid in registration.

Comment: @Mann87 do you want it without `_`, `..` and `-` right ?

Comment: I updated my question with another way, please check it

Answer (score 3):

Why not use http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

```
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
  echo("$email is a valid email address");
} else {
  echo("$email is not a valid email address");
}
```

See filter definition here. http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

> Validates whether the value is a valid e-mail address.
>
> In general, this validates e-mail addresses against the syntax in RFC
>   822, with the exceptions that comments and whitespace folding and
>   dotless domain names are not supported.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your good answer. In normal PHP Project I would say this is the best answer, but in our case not usable. I search a right regex code to use.

Comment: I'm aware that sometimes native function are not strict enough. I thought that  maybe the "exceptions that comments and whitespace folding and dotless domain names are not supported." part would cover your needs. Still a good bet :)

Comment: @Mann87 Why is it not usable? You haven't identified any restrictions in your question.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Yes right I forget it in my question. Sorry. It is not usable because of code structure & php version. So I realy need an exp.

Comment: @Mann87 `filter_var()` has been in PHP since v5.2.0 which is over 10 years old -- if you're using a version older than that, you have much more serious issues to worry about...

Comment: @AlexHowansky yes can be that this php version can it, but this don't solve the problem of code structure I am not allowed to change it. I only change the regex there.

Comment: If you take the time to look at http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php there is alot of ambiguity about FILTER_VALIDATE_FILTER and it might not works as expected from one subversion to the other. Also be noted "The FILTER_FLAG_EMAIL_UNICODE seems to only be available at PHP 7+ but this is missing from the documentation." (ref: http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.flags.php).